Why narrowing inside closures does not work with property objects but works with declared variables?
I'm trying to understand why Typescript cannot correctly get the type of an object property parameter, that can be undefined, inside an inner function but when that same property is assigned to its own variable in the outer function scope the narrowing happens seamlessly.
I have this snippet to reproduce the problem:
type MyType = {
    optional?: string
}

(arr: string[], param: MyType) => {

    if (param.optional) {
        const includes = arr.includes(param.optional)  // <-- Fine

        arr.filter(function (item) {
            return item.includes(param.optional)  // <-- Wrong! Type undefined is not assignable...
        })
    }
}

Within the if branch, Typescript warns me about the use of param.optional inside the filter inner function because it could be string | undefined, whether when it is used inside the arr.includes(param.optional) there are no warnings at all.
It seems very odd to me because if instead of using param.optional I assigned that same value to its own variable Typescript is able to narrow its type (string) perfectly.
type MyType = {
    optional?: string
}

(arr: string[], param: MyType) => {
    const variable = param.optional

    if (variable) {
        const includes = arr.includes(variable)  // <-- Fine

        arr.filter(function (item) {
            return item.includes(variable)  // <-- Fine
        })
    }
}

Why is this behaviour happening? What does it have to do with the object itself (because if the parameter is just a primitive optional value string | undefined this problem does not occur)?

Because it's not safe to do so in the general case.
TypeScript doesn't know what filter does, so it doesn't know when its callback is called (synchronously now, or asynchronously later) and thus doesn't know whether the object gets changed by other code outside the scope of the function. Changes by code outside the function could invalidate the type guard.
But with your (amusingly-named) variable constant, TypeScript knows that the value can't change, so the type guard can be applied. It even works if you use let instead of const, because TypeScript can see that there aren't any assignments to variable. (But if you used let and added variable = undefined; after the filter call, you'd get the same error you get with param.optional, because again TypeScript doesn't know when the callback's code runs relative to that assignment: example.)

I see it clearer now, thanks! But what's the difference between having an optional primitive parameter (string | undefined) and an object parameter with an optional attribute (MyType.optional)?
Because in the first example if there are no assignments to the parameter Typescript gets every type correctly, but if the parameter is an object with an optional attribute then independently whether there're or aren't any assignments to the parameter Typescript warns me about the type in the inner function.
I understand the first case but not why in the second warns no matter what

@rmoret - There are no assignments to the parameter's property in that code, but the parameter is an object that is passed into the function. The code calling the function could assign to the property.
